# Drawing a "spider" web of arrows in tikz-cd [for Halloween]

Tags: align, diagrams, xy-pic, tikz-cd, draw

For Halloween or not, I am trying to make the following-like "spider" web diagram through tikzcd, roughly like this (of course I am just drawing the more ugly version of it, the arrow should be thin) 
[image]
but I have failed embarrassingly so far:
[image]
I failed because I wanted to aim for the following criteria:

1. ai and aii align in the same vertical axis,
2. b itself is on its vertical axis
3. ci, ciii and cii align in the same vertical axis,
4. d itself is on its vertical axis
5. edi and eiii align in the same vertical axis,
6. f itself is on its vertical axis
7. The horizontal distance between the neighbor vertical axes of the same initial alphabets are the same (namely, the distance between the vertical a axis, the vertical b axis, the vertical c axis, the vertical d axis, the vertical e axis, the vertical f axis are the same).

Here is my minimal work template and my trial:

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
BPin^-\ar[d]\\
BO\ar[r,"w_1^2+w_2"] &K(\Z/2,2)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Could you please kindly provide me a guideline and a possible sample to it?

I am happy to use `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` or `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`. You are also allowed to use bend (e.g `\ar[uur,bend left= ...,""]` if you wish)

Thank you in advance to the Halloween superhero experts here!! :-)

[image][image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a `matrix of math nodes` (section 57.1, page 646 of the current 
[tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual). This gives you an easy way of laying out `b`, `d`, `f`, etc. in a grid so that you automatically get your vertical alignment. Once you have all of the vertices in place then you can draw the many edges using a `\foreach` statement to produce:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
          & b &    & d &    & f\\
        ai&   & ci &   &cdi &\\
          &   &ciii&   &eiii\\
       aii&   &cii\\
       };
       \foreach \a/\b in {1-2/1-4, 1-4/1-6, 2-1/2-3, 2-3/2-5, 
                          3-3/3-5, 4-1/4-3, 2-1/1-2, 2-3/1-4, 
                          2-5/1-6, 3-3/2-5, 3-5/1-6, 4-1/3-3, 
                          4-3/3-5, 2-1/3-3, 3-3/1-4, 4-3/1-4} {
          \draw[thick,->](M-\a)--(M-\b);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `(M)` after `\matrix` means that the nodes have labels `(M-1-2)`, `(M-1-4)` etc. in the non-empty cells (with the option `nodes in empty cells` you can have nodes in the empty cells too). You can change `(M)` to anything you like.

You can adjust the spacing by changing `row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm` to suit your tastes.

Comment: You forgot the arrow between aii and b :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oops, sorry! Exercise for the reader:)

Comment: You wanted to see if s/he is attentive :)

Comment: thanks +1, this looks nice. I think it will be compatible to minipage for each symbol, yes or no? :-)

Comment: @wonderich My understanding is that each element in the matrix is a `tikz` node. To some extend these function like mini-pages, perhaps, but they are not the same.

Comment: @Andrew, it helps. I wonder if I like to shift the figure displacement, (like using   \makebox[\textwidth][r]{} \hspace*{-32mm} ), do you know the compatibility? Does it work?

Comment: @wonderich Do you want to shift the entire diagram or just part of it? To shift the `tikzpicture` you could just put `\kern-32mm` in front of it but there is probably a cleaner way with some tikz commands. I can look tomorrow if can say more precisely what you want.

Comment: @Andrew. this works -- you must be a genius! Super fast heroic response.

Comment: @wonderich I think that you are underselling geniuses and overselling those who are obsessed with TeX!

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple to do it with `tikz-cd`.

You can also choose the arrow tip you like with:

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=...}}
```

and fine tune the arrow position, with:

```
end anchor={[shift={(...,...)}]}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=Latex}}% arrow tip

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
         & b\ar[rr] &  & d\ar[rr] &  & f\\
        ai \ar[ur]\ar[rr]\ar[drr] &  & ci\ar[ur]\ar[rr] &  & edi\ar[ur]\\
         &  & ciii\ar[rru]\ar[rr]\ar[ruu] &  & eiii\ar[uur]\\
        aii\ar[uuur]\ar[urr]\ar[rr] &  & cii\ar[rru]\ar[uuur,end anchor={[shift={(2pt,-1pt)}]} % fine tuning of the arrow position
        ]
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't know that the syntax for arrows was so flexible.

Comment: @Andrew Of course it is! ;)

Comment: thanks +1, this looks nice. I think it will be compatible to replace  each symbol for minipage, yes or no? :-)

Comment: @wonderich Do you intend to put a `minipage` instead of the letters?